# Show that a homogeneous ideal  in $[_0, _1, … , _]$ is prime if and only if $ ≠ ⟨1⟩$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was given this question Show that a homogeneous ideal  in $[_0, _1, … , _]$ is prime if and only if $ ≠ ⟨1⟩$ and, for all homogeneous polynomials $,  ∈ $, the relation $  ∈ $ implies that $ ∈ $ or $ ∈ $.

I think I can prove the last part but I am stuck on proving its true if and  only if $ ≠ ⟨1⟩$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: ah, I believe you are misreading the question. it is *not* the case that a homogeneous ideal is prime if and only if it is not equal to $\langle 1\rangle$; for instance, consider the ideal $\langle x^2\rangle$ in $\mathbb{K}[x]$, which is homogeneous and proper but not prime. the question is asking you to showing that a homogeneous ideal in $\mathbb{K}[\overline{x}]$ is prime if and only if it is not equal to $\langle 1\rangle$ *and* satisfies the condition that $fg\in I$ implies $f\in I$ or $g\in I$, for all homogeneous polynomials $f,g\in\mathbb{K}[\overline{x}]$

Comment: Oh yes I see that now, thank you!